# What should be the largest size of a file for MATLAB import?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to import a (.txt) data file to MATLAB(2013a). The file is 64,261 KB.  Every time I click on import data, the program freezes.
Is there a limit for the file size or is it just my machine?

Comment: There is no limit other than the amount of RAM on your computer, but do keep in mind that when you import something it has to read that file and save it into either a string or vector, depending on import method, which could take a while. A 64MB text file sure has a lot of text, so be patient.

Comment: 64MB is far away from any limit, there must be some other reason for the freeze.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure you're using [memmapfile()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html). MATLAB (your OS) can support up to 2 GB on a 32 bit system and 256 TB on a 64 bit system. For details, see:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/overview-of-memory-mapping.html

Comment: `memmapfile` is not appropriate for a text file